# Cómo activar la ubicación del celular a traves de Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, android-intent, gps

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi aplicación active el icono de Ubicación de la parte superior (menú) que todos tenemos en el celula.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que busqué un código y éste hace que me salga una ventana de configuración y tu tienes que activar la Ubicación, pero lo que yo quiero para que mi aplicación se vea mejor, es que al darle click a un botón este me active de manera automática la ubicación (icono del celular).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que encontré:

```
 ActivarGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;


                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Activar mapa?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Si", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
            }
        });
```

***La pregunta sería, ¿Como puedo hacer para que al darle click en el botón que dice: "ACTIVAR GPS" de frente me active el ícono de Ubicación de la parte superior del celular? Ayuda por favor***

Answer (score 0):

Para pedir cualquier permiso necesitas seguir un procedimiento similar.

Desde que se introdujo la API de Activity Result, la forma adecuada de hacerlo mediante un objeto [`ActivityResultLauncher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher) que se obtiene llamando a la función [`registerForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).

Esta función recibe una instancia de la acción a realizar como primer parámetro y una instancia que se encarga de recibir el resultado de la acción como segundo parámetro. Más información [aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Para los permisos, el "contrato", como le llama la API es [`ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions).

Este objeto devuelto por `registerForActivityResult` lo guardas y realizas la acción mediante su método `launch` pasando los parámetros esperados. En este caso los parámetros serían los permisos a pedir.

Este es el ejemplo que brinda [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#user-choice-affects-permission-grants):

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> locationPermissionRequest =
    registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts
        .RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
            // Aquí puedes verificar que los permisos hayan sido otorgados.
            // La documentación lo hace así:

            Boolean fineLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
            Boolean coarseLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,false);
            if (fineLocationGranted != null && fineLocationGranted) {
                // Acceso a ubicación precisa concedido.
            } else if (coarseLocationGranted != null && coarseLocationGranted) {
                // Acceso a ubicación aproximada solamente concedido 
            } else {
                // Ningún permiso fue aceptado.
            }
        }
    );
```

Entonces cuando quieras solicitar el permiso, llamas a la función [`launch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher#launch(I)) con los permisos que quieres obtener:

```
locationPermissionRequest.launch(new String[] {
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
});
```

Cabe mencionar que todo el código debería estar en clase que herede de [`ActivityResultCaller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller), por ejemplo [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity).