# startActivityForResult deprecated en Java

Tags: java, android

soy nuevo en desarrollo de apps y no tengo mucha experiencia en esto, me gastaría saber como actualizar startActivityForResult de mi app desarrollada en java porque por mas que miro no logro entender como hacerlo.

Aqui dejo el startActivityForResult

```
imagen.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent,galery_pick);
});
```

Aqui dejo el onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //si requestcode es igual a galerypick y resultcode  es igual a resultok y data es diferente de nulo..
    if(requestCode==galery_pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null){

        //creamos una imagen de tipo uri que sera igual a data.getdata()
        Uri imagenUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imagenUri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1).start(this);
    }
    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(resultCode== RESULT_OK){
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            //guardaremos las fotos con el id del usuario .jpg
            StorageReference filePath = userImagen.child(currentUserId+".jpg");
            final File url = new File(resultUri.getPath());
            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    userImagen.child(currentUserId+".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                        final String downloadUri = uri.toString();
                        userRef.child(currentUserId).child("imagen").setValue(downloadUri).addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                            if (task1.isSuccessful()){
                                Picasso.get().load(downloadUri).into(imagen);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }else{
                                String mensaje = task1.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(ConfiguracionAdminActivity.this, "Error: "+mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Imagen no soportada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Se que aun funciona pero me gustaria poder actualizarlo, y mejor aun, entenderlo.

Comment: Probaste a mirar en la documentación y cursos de android? Porque literalmente tienen un cursito precisamente sobre esto... https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: No es exactamente lo mismo, pero la base es la misma quizá te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568279/169744) que di quizá la pregunta se pueda considerar duplicada.

Comment: Aunque salga deprecated sigue funcionando. Es porque es una metodo obsoleto pero sigue en funcionamiento aunque salga tachado.